# Realistic look for subterranean humanoid race

Tags: evolution, humanoid, underground

So i have been playing around with the idea of a world that due to its orbit (it is both quite a bit away from it's parent star and due to its orbit permanently between two much bigger planets) has something of a permanent night going on (brightest part of day would look like twilight on earth). The planet is however not frozen becuase it is heated by internal processes. 
The race inhabiting this world primarily lives inside humongous cave systems that are naturally lighted by fluorescent/phosphorescent (i Always mix those up) Crystals verying from pebble to boulder/column size.

So i kinda figured that a race living in permanent low light conditions like this would probably have a very light (if not outright milky white) skin and probably red eyes (i sure do not plan on making them blind)

What i want to know is, taking into account my world description above, if my idea of how they should look (light/pale/white skin and red eyes) is realistic and if not what would be more believable in terms of outward appearance

Answer (score 1):

For pale skin yes, a lot of the pigmentation in animal skin is to protect from radiation from the sun. It would be reasonable for them to have white, near transluscent skin if you wanted them to.

As for the eyes, I suppose you mean that their irises are red. I believe that the colour of your iris has no impact on it absorption of light. You might want to look into the eyes of nocturnal or subterranean animals here on earth, like the [naked mole rat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naked_mole-rat).

Answer (score 1):

A lot depends on how long these creatures have been living underground and how long they spend underground. If the answer is they always live underground and always have done (millions of years) then they would have adapted to the dark and would have no eyes. In such a case they might have evolved some form of echo location like bats so might look rather odd and bat like.

If they spend some time in the light or have only recently gone underground then their eyes might well remain useful and similar to ours.

Any number of in between cases can be imagined which would result in degreed of poor eye sight. If any light sources were to be found underground or the creatures did not live far below the surface another possibility is the development of much better vision as in nocturnal animals.

Answer (score 0):

If they are outright aliens they can look however you want.  The Horta is a good example.  It looks to me like nerf balls stuck together with expanding foam, and probably was.
https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Horta

If you want them to look like Edgar Winter you can propose that they are descended from a human (or if farther back Homo genus) stock, which was moved to this planet by some higher force and which subsequently has evolved to be cave adapted.   Remember that for cave people Vitamin D will be an issue.  Maximizing vitamin D is why white people are white (for cave animals it is different; losing pigment has no evolutionary cost so sometimes they lose it).  As regards vitamin D deficiency you could have your human stock aliens all be rachitic dwarves or have them eat a lot of space muktuk.